# How to findElements from a returned findElement in selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, mocha.js, ui-automation

Its general knowledge that in Java, the easiest way to accomplish this is by

```
List <WebElement> listItems=findElement(by.selector(selector)).findElements(by.selector(selector));
```

The question is how do you accomplish this in Javascript. I have searched online to no avail.

I use Selenium-Mocha-chai.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is asynchronous, and doing it via promises, it would something like:

```
var listItems;
driver.findElement(By.selector(selector))
  .then(function(element){
    return element.findElements(By.selector(selector2));
  }).then(function(elements){
    listItems=elements;
    // do some stuff...
  }).catch(function(e){ // error handler
    console.error(e);
  })
```